# Nested classes are not serializable in python when trying JSON dump

Tags: json, dictionary, serialization

I currently have two classes in Python like these ones

```
class person:
    age=""
    name=""
    ranking = {}

    def addRanking():
    #Do Whatever treatment and add to the ranking dict

class ranking:
    semester = ""
    position = ""
    gpa = ""
```

I have my list of person as a dictionary called `dictP` `json.dumps()` this dictionary but it seems that it doesn't work. Here is my function to dump to JSON

```
def toJson():
    jsonfile = open('dict.json', 'w')
    print(json.dump(listP, jsonfile))
```

I get the famous:  is not JSON serializable.

Would you know what I can do to help this problem. I thought that having two dictionaries (which are serializable) would avoid this kind of issue, but apparently not.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Here is an example (typed on my phone sorry for typos, I'm not sure it does run but it's so you get the idea):

```
class person:
    age=""
    name=""
    ranking = {}

    def __init__(self, age, name):
        self.age = age
        self.name = name
        self.ranking = {}

    def addRanking(self,semester,position,gpa):
        #if the semester is not already present in the data for that person
            self.ranking[semester] = make_ranking(semester,position,gpa)

class ranking:
    semester = ""
    position = ""
    gpa = ""

    def __init__(self, semester, position, gpa):
        self.semester = semester
        self.position = position
        self.gpa = gpa

dictP = {}


def make_person(age, name):
    # Some stuff happens there
    return person(age,name)

def make_ranking(semester,postion,gpa):
    #some computation there
    return ranking(semester,position,gpa)

def pretending_to_read_csv():
    age = 12
    name = "Alice"
    p = make_person(age, name)
    dictP["1"] = p

    age = 13
    name = "Alice"
    p = make_person(age, name)
    dictP["2"] = p

    #We read a csv for ranking that gives us an ID 
    semester = 1
    position = 4 
    gpa = 3.2
    id = 1 

    dictP["1"].addRanking(semester, position, gpa)

    semester = 2
    position = 4 
    gpa = 3.2
    id = 1 

    dictP["1"].addRanking(semester, position, gpa)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a dictionary to be serializable, note that all the keys & values in that dictionary must be serializable as well. You did not show us what `listP` contains, but I'm guessing it's something like this:

```
>>> listP
[<__main__.person instance at 0x107b65290>, <__main__.person instance at 0x107b65368>]
```

Python instances are not serializable.

I think you want a list of dictionaries, which would look like this:

```
>>> listP
[{'ranking': {}, 'age': 10, 'name': 'fred'}, {'ranking': {}, 'age': 20, 'name': 'mary'}]
```

This would serialize as you expect:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(listP)
'[{"ranking": {}, "age": 10, "name": "fred"}, {"ranking": {}, "age": 20, "name": "mary"}]'
```

---

**UPDATE**

(Thanks for adding example code.)

```
>>> pretending_to_read_csv()
>>> dictP
{'1': <__main__.person instance at 0x107b65368>, '2': <__main__.person instance at 0x107b863b0>}
```

Recall that user-defined classes cannot be serialized automatically. It's possible to extend the `JSONEncoder` directly to handle these cases, but all you really need is a function that can turn your object into a dictionary comprised entirely of primitives.

```
def convert_ranking(ranking):
    return {
        "semester": ranking.semester,
        "position": ranking.position,
        "gpa": ranking.gpa}

def convert_person(person):
    return {
        "age": person.age,
        "name": person.name,
        "ranking": {semester: convert_ranking(ranking) for semester, ranking in person.ranking.iteritems()}}
```

One more dictionary comprehension to actually do the conversion and you're all set:

```
>>> new_dict = {person_id: convert_person(person) for person_id, person in dictP.iteritems()}
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(new_dict)
{'1': {'age': 12,
       'name': 'Alice',
       'ranking': {1: {'gpa': 3.2, 'position': 4, 'semester': 1},
                   2: {'gpa': 3.2, 'position': 4, 'semester': 2}}},
 '2': {'age': 13, 'name': 'Alice', 'ranking': {}}}
```

Since no user-defined objects are stuffed in there, this will serialize as you hope:

```
>>> json.dumps(new_dict)
'{"1": {"ranking": {"1": {"position": 4, "semester": 1, "gpa": 3.2}, "2": {"position": 4, "semester": 2, "gpa": 3.2}}, "age": 12, "name": "Alice"}, "2": {"ranking": {}, "age": 13, "name": "Alice"}}'
```

Comment: Currently on the phone so it’s hard to look at my code or comment more (or even make sense of everything you said) but my ListP contains an ID and an instance of Perso.

Comment: Can you add a copy of the `listP` you're working with to your question?

Comment: well I just build it on the fly while reading a bunch of CSVs but it's basically the key is an ID and the value is an instance of Person

Comment: Ok, that is the root of your issue: an instance of your `person` class is not serializable, whether it's the value of a dictionary or an element in a list.

Comment: so I have my dictionary with instances of person and then each instance of person got instances of rankings... How should I proceed. This thing is seriously confusing me... Can you edit your answer ?

Comment: forgot to mention, thanks for the information you have given me so far :)

Comment: Sure, glad to flesh out my answer. I need you to add an example data structure to your question though, so I don't have to guess at it. Bonus points if you add code that I can run to create that data structure myself, so I don't need to do it by hand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177686/discussion-between-lbes-and-chris).

Comment: I just did add what is close to an MWE

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I just saw that and I will try right away :). Thanks for the extra explanations in your update too. I've seen loads of posts saying you can't serialize objects but none giving any kind of explanations :).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Just tested on this example and it works perfectly. Now I have slightly more complicated classes. Could I somehow contact you privately for one or two questions?

Answer (score 1):

You can try calling `json.dump` on the `.__dict__` member of your instance. You say that you have a list of person instances so try doing something like this:

```
listJSON = []
for p in listP
    #append the value of the dictionary containing data about your person instance to a list
    listJSON.append(p.__dict__)
json.dump(listJSON, jsonfile)
```

If you are storing your person instances in a dictionary like so: `dictP = {'person1': p1, 'person2': p2}` this solution will loop through the keys and change their corresponding values to the `__dict__` member of the instance:

```
for key in dictP:
    dictP[key] = dictP[key].__dict__
json.dump(dictP, jsonfile)
```

Comment: I actually have a dictionary of Person. So what would happen then ? Does t change anything to call .__dict__?

Comment: will try that in a couple of hours. Currently on the phone.